# VIM , y+ and trailing characters

Tags: vim

While i was trying to copy the text selected in VIM into system clipboard buffer , it tells me an error:

[image: Result of y+]

I firstly select text in visual mode , and type in `:y+` , and the error pop up , won't work for `:y +` as well

P.S: it's just a new file not saved to disk , so i don't think it's problem with file format, although many people on google say so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `"*y`

Keep in mind that this feature works only within `clipboard` enabled vim.

`:version` to check if `clipboard` is enabled.

Comment: thanks , i figured out the problem , clipboard option is not enabled

Answer (score 1):

On MacOs, enabling `clipboard` fixes the problem but also to have `clipboard` enabled(`+`), I had to upgrade VIm version to be 8, where you can see `+clipboard` is enabled,

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 22 2017 06:41:01)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-577
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xpm
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.1/lib/perl5/5.24.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -F/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks -framework Python   -lruby.2.4.1 -lobjc
```

Then `:%y+` works perfectly with `vim filename`.

[image: yank to clipboard]

### Refs

[Mac OS X clipboard sharing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing)

[Vim & Mac: How to copy to clipboard without pbcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20187646/432903)